# Why some compiler shows unfavorable output for a specific input?

Tags: c++

Look at this code, In my VS code or some online compilers it gives favorable output, but when I'm submitting this on HackerRank or this online [compiler](http://cpp.sh/) I'm getting wrong output but only when I provide  `input` as: 1 1 1 100...and I'm not able to spot the Error?..I'm providing question for reference.

```
 /*There will be two arrays of integers. Determine all integers that satisfy 
 the following two conditions:
 The elements of the first array are all factors of the integer being 
 considered
 The integer being considered is a factor of all elements of the second array
 These numbers are referred to as being between the two arrays. Determine how 
 many such numbers exist.
  */

 #include <iostream>

int main()
{
int count1, count2;
int num1[20], num2[20];


std::cin >> count1 >> count2;


for (int i = 0; i < count1; i++)
{
    std::cin >> num1[i];
}


for (int i = 0; i < count2; i++)
{
    std::cin >> num2[i];
}

int occurence_firstarray = 0, occurence_secondarray = 0, totalvalid_occurence = 0;

for (int i = num1[count1 - 1]; i < num2[1]; i++)
{
    occurence_firstarray = 0;
    occurence_secondarray = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < count1; j++)
    {
        if (i % num1[j] == 0)
        {
            occurence_firstarray++;
        }
    }

    if (occurence_firstarray == count1)
    {
        for (int p = 0; p < count2; p++)
        {
            if (num2[p] % i == 0)
            {
                occurence_secondarray++;
            }
        }
    }

    if (occurence_secondarray == count2)
    {
        totalvalid_occurence++;
    }
  }

  std::cout <<  totalvalid_occurence;
  return (0);
 }
```

Comment: Different compilers different behaviour, 99 times out of ten it means undefined behaviour. What makes you sure that you never access beyond your small arrays? You do not check the numbers you are using as indexes against the sizes.

Comment: The first step in debugging code like this is to determine what input values are causing problems, and hard-code those values rather than read them in. That way you have a reproducible test case without having to worry about typing the values correctly. That also gives you something you can post here, so that people can look at your code and maybe see what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your `inputs`: 1 1 1 100,

What are you doing in this code is You are pointing on index beyond your second array's size limit `i < num2[1]`, this is why you are getting wrong outputs.

Do some changes as,  `i <= num2[0];`